# How do I use "argc" in an efi shell?

Tags: c, uefi

Currently I am programming with efi API.

How do I use in an efi programing ? 
I want to know how to write argv and argc in efi.

c code written till now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  int i;
  printf("Program name is %s \n",argv[0]);
  if (argc <2)
     printf("argument is no exist \n");
 else 
   for (i=0;i<argc;i++)
     printf ("argv[%d] = %s \n",i,argv[i]);
 }
```

Comment: What's "efi"?  You show how to use it - what more do you need?

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're trying to achieve here. Could you provide a sample run of your program, the results that it gave you, and what you expected the results to be?

Comment: It doesn't matter UEFI shell it is or Linux or Windows. argc, argv is part of the standard and it works out-of-the-box everywhere. You have to be more specific what exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: It is used in the c language as the text. But how do you use it in UEFI SHELL? C Language and grammar are different.

Comment: In addition, it compiles in VISUAL STUDIO 2015 by using EFI API (edk2) and runs it as an efi file in UEFI SHELL.

Comment: Sample source:https://github.com/ionescu007/VisualUefi

Comment: So, how do you run it?

Answer (score 0):

`argc`, `argv` and `main` are standard library concepts, and don't directly translate to UEFI applications.

On a generic level:

- UEFI applications use only UEFI interfaces
- UEFI Shell applications can also rely on interfaces provided by the UEFI Shell (but will not run correctly outside the shell)

In either case, when the application launches, its entry point will only be passed a pointer to the UEFI System Table and an *Image Handle*, providing the link to information about how the current image was invoked.

Pure UEFI applications have only the `EFI_LOADED_IMAGE_PROTOCOL` installed on their image handle. UEFI Shell applications also have the `EFI_SHELL_PARAMETERS_PROTOCOL`.

The `EFI_SHELL_PARAMETERS_PROTOCOL` gives you access to argc/argv constructs. Without this, you're down to parsing `EFI_LOADED_IMAGE_PROTOCOL.LoadOptions` manually.

You can find the details of these protocols in the *UEFI Specification* and the *UEFI Shell Specification*, [from the UEFI Forum website](http://uefi.org/specifications/).

Of course, abstracting frameworks like gnu-efi (and maybe VisualUefi) may hide the underlying mechanics, or provide alternative means for getting at them.`